# Get Visual studio project name xxxxx.vcxproj from DLL name

Tags: dll, static-libraries

We have one centralized system to build all projects which is often heavily loaded as no of projects is too large, thus performance is decreased.

I want to share this load across few other systems by distributing **DLLs** across all systems and build them independently so that build performance is increased.

For this I want to get VS project name(***.vcxproj**) from DLL name which is being built so that I can get list of static libraries required to build that DLL by using project name.

For example-
DLL name is Test.dll and it requires one static library A.lib to build then I can get that from VS solution Test.vcxproj.

But when DLL name is different than solution name then it fails.
Is there any other way to get shared library list using DLL name?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the filename of your vcxproj open that file. If the output filename is changed you will find an entry Project/PropertyGroup/TargetName containing the modified one.